# Azure Function v4 .net6 Event Hub Trigger - how to get EnqueuedTimeUTC?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I have a working Azure Functions app, with an Event Hub trigger.
It's using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker 1.10, functions runtime 4, .Net 6 and running as Isolated (not in-process).

The current function signature looks like:

```cs
    Function("MyFunction")]
        public async Task Run([EventHubTrigger("my-eventhub",
            ConsumerGroup = "a-consumer-group",
            Connection = "EventHub.ConnectionString")] string[] messages)
        {
         //Do stuff
        }
```

I would like to expand this to grab the Enqueue Time (the time at which the event ended up at the Event Hub).

So, i realise in Functions runtime v4, that i can't grab EventData[] like i could in older verions, instead i should use the BindingContext.

So i tried this:

```cs
    Function("MyFunction")]
        public async Task Run([EventHubTrigger("my-eventhub",
            ConsumerGroup = "a-consumer-group",
            Connection = "EventHub.ConnectionString")] string[] messages, FunctionContext context)
        {
            var data = context.BindingContext.BindingData["enqueuedTimeUtcArray"];
        
            //data would always be empty
        }
```

Figuring that this was the wrong approach, and seeing further examples breaking fields down, i tried the following:

```cs
    Function("MyFunction")]
        public async Task Run([EventHubTrigger("my-eventhub",
            ConsumerGroup = "a-consumer-group",
            Connection = "EventHub.ConnectionString")] string[] messages,
            DateTime[] enqueuedTimeUtcArray,
            long[] sequenceNumberArray,
            string[] offsetArray,
            Dictionary<string, JsonElement>[] propertiesArray,
            Dictionary<string, JsonElement>[] systemPropertiesArray))
        {
            var data = enqueuedTimeUtcArray;
        
            //data would always be empty
    }
```

I've tried various variations on those themes, including referencing the following:

- https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/pull/508/commits/590e69b9f9fad14730daf0226fce2b93c9acb289
- https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/wiki/.NET-Worker-bindings#using-method-attributes-works-if-you-only-have-one-output-binding
- https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/283
- https://dev.to/kenakamu/azure-function-and-net-5-how-to-get-eventdata-for-event-hub-input-binding-3bmm

The functions still trigger, and the functionality it provides (replaced with //do stuff) still goes off without a hitch, but still no EnqueueTimes... what am i doing wrong?

Comment: "i realise in Functions runtime v4, that i can't grab EventData[] like i could in older verions," why not?  It's still documented as working: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp

Comment: That would be for an in-process one, surely? I'm running Isolated, which suggests i use "FunctionContext context". Or, is the documentation saying something different than i am reading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For isolated functions you have to dig around in the FunctionContext to get this data.  The message enqueue times are available as a JSON array:

```
    [Function("EventHubTrigger1")]
    public void Run([EventHubTrigger("test", Connection = "myhub_all_EVENTHUB")] string[] input, FunctionContext context)
    {

        string enquedTimes = context.BindingContext.BindingData["EnqueuedTimeUtcArray"];

        _logger.LogInformation($"First Event Hubs triggered message: {input[0]}");
    }
```

Adding a function argument also worked:

```
public void Run([EventHubTrigger("test", Connection = "myhub_all_EVENTHUB")] string[] input, string[] enqueuedTimeUtcArray)
```

Comment: This is weird - it's the second code sample i posted in my Question. I have tried uppercase first letter: EnqueuedTimeUtcArray and lowercase first letter: enqueudTimeUtcArray
Neither worked.
Have you tested this locally and confirmed it works for you? If so - i may have issues elsewhere.

Comment: Yes.  I tested locally with a new Function project in Visual Studio 2022

Comment: Thanks for your efforts David, i will create a new project and copy stuff over in the worst case then! Still did not get this working for some reason.

Comment: You may need to update your local functions runtime too.

Comment: Finally got it resolved - your answer was correct. My PC appears to have been at fault somehow. I've posted another answer with exactly how i ended up at the result, too.

Answer (score 2):

For those reading in future, here's how the final, working solution looked, with massive help from David Browne in the comments:

```cs
        Function("MyFunction")]
        public async Task Run([EventHubTrigger("my-eventhub",
            ConsumerGroup = "a-consumer-group",
            Connection = "EventHub.ConnectionString")] string[] messages, FunctionContext context)
        {
            var data = context.BindingContext.BindingData["enqueuedTimeUtcArray"];
        
            var listOfDateTimes = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string[]>(data["EnqueuedTimeUtcArray"].ToString())
                        .Select(a => DateTime.Parse(a.ToString())).ToList()

          //Do stuff
        }
```

I finally started receiving data from the FunctionContext after restarting my PC (I have no idea...), then realized i'd received a json array of strings, which were datetime compatible.
So, deserializing them was the answer.